# What reaction takes place here?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, aldol-reaction

[image]

Upon reading the given question, I realized that:

The first reaction is an aldol condensation reaction between the given compound and formaldehyde.

So the product after 1st step is:

[image]

Now, the second part has thrown me off. The current ketone has no $\alpha$ hydrogen left. Condensation reactions are out of the question.
Cannizzaro reaction can not take place as this is a ketone (and not an aldehyde) also the medium is now acidic.
However, I saw one possibility of formation of hemi-acetals.
(I did not think about full acetals, as such a structure was not present in the given options to this question)

Which gave me the following product:

[image]

However, the answer provided seems to be not this.
The given answer is this:

[image]

Can someone give a suggestion that where I want wrong and/or how could I reach the answer and also what was wrong in my thinking as well?

This question is taken from the JEE(A)-2016 [Paper - 2]

Comment: If that ketone part would've been an alcohol, an easy intramolecular reaction would take place - giving me a full acetal as well as the answer...if only.

Comment: @Waylander, thanks for your input. Amazing. However, when my hemi-acetal is formed, I am already on step (ii). At step (ii), an acidic medium is provided instead of a strongly basic one that is needed for Cannizzaro reaction.

Comment: You have misidentified the intermediate at the end of step i. The formaldehyde/NaOH conditions will deliver the diol (intermediate 9 in the scheme in the linked answer) through aldol followed by crossed Cannizzaro. The conditions for step ii are for forming the acetal only.

Comment: @Waylander, you're correct. Thanks for the explanation. Everything seems to fall in place now.

Answer (score -1):

I think a cross Cannizzaro with the Ketone and Formaldehyde takes place. The ketone give the alcohol and Formaldehyde formiate. In a second step a full acetal will be created with formaldehyd and now the Diole.
Sorry I cannot add comments here. So use answer function.

Comment: Isn't it that Cannizzaro reactions happen only between two aldehydes? Sure that there are no $\alpha$ hydrogen present, but they aren't aldehydes either.

Comment: It is a "special case" Cannizaro. See the answer linked in the comments for the mechanism.